# Recent history of Call logs! (Not actually call log)

Tags: nexus-5, call-history

Few days ago, I tried to recharge my phone's balance through recharge card but couldn't do it due to the network problem. Generally, here in Nepal, we recharge the pre-paid balance by dialing `*411*xxx(13 digit pin)xxx#`. Since, I couldn't do it that time, I placed that card somewhere in my room and lost it.
Now my question is, can I look for that dial history (log)? Such codes cannot be seen in normal call log. That must be stored somewhere right?

Comment: If it's not in the normal call log, it's probably not stored anywhere in the phone.

Comment: Mostly everything is saved on the electronic devices now days. Hope it does too.